# nodejs vm memory leaks

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, virtual-machine

Using node 0.12.6 or iojs 2.3.3.
Next code give me memory leaks.

```
var vm = require("vm");
var result;
var pool = {test:42};

setInterval(function () {
    context = vm.createContext(pool);
    result = vm.runInContext("test=56;", pool);
    console.log(pool);
    console.log(parseInt(process.memoryUsage().heapTotal / 1024 / 1024));
}, 2);
```

Does anybody have idea how to resolve this problem?
Thanks.